# html progress bar not working in android browsers

Tags: android, browser, web-applications, progress-bar

I have a web app that has a progress bar. It works fine in the desktop browser, but doesn't animate in android browsers. I tried both html5 progress element and jquery approaches. They work in the the desktop, but not in the android browsers. Any insight into this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code showing the two different approaches you've tried? Also which browser are you using on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because a link I had on my page was http, not https. Changed this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```